# Is there any way to represent 4 byte number as a 16 byte number?

Tags: c, libgcrypt

I ***have*** to encrypt some data using a 4 byte IV. However, the encryption algorithm that I am using (AES128)needs a 16 byte (128 bit) key. Say, my code is as follows:

```
#include<gcrypt.h>
void encrypt(){
    int IV = 6174;
    gcry_cipher_hd_t hd;        
    errStatus = gcry_cipher_open(&hd, GCRY_CIPHER_AES128, GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_CBC, 0);
    errStatus = gcry_cipher_setkey(hd, keyBuffer, 16);
    gcry_cipher_setiv(hd, &IV, 16);
    gcry_cipher_encrypt(hd, output, 16, bytesToEncrypt, 16);
}
```

Say `keyBuffer` contains a 16 byte key and `bytes,`output` are my input and output respectively. How do I go about properly giving the IV?

Comment: This seems like the wrong thing to do. A small IV will compromise encryption security. And if you are using a constant IV like in your example, it will be greatly compromised. The IV is supposed to be random and different for each message that is encrypted.

Comment: I know. Its just a class exercise to get familiar with crypto libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code just for avoiding buffer overflow?  I haven't tested this myself, though

```
int IV[4] = { 6174 }; // { 6174, 0, 0, 0 }
```

Comment: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" :-(

Comment: `gcc -O0 -g` (oh-zero gee) will produce a binary suitable for debugging.  Can you run the debug binary under `gdb` to see exactly where the SEGV happened?  And you can type `bt` to show the stack frames. http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html